# Отправка пакета

Tags: java, http

Здравствуйте.

Нужно отправить один единственный пакет, без никаких кук и замысловатых параметров, но в Charles я получаю одно, а с помощью нижеизложенного кода - другое. Помогите разобраться в причинах.

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
 import java.net.URL;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.Map;

  public class ODbrute {
  static String user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36                  (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.45 Safari/537.36";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String response = sendRequest("http://ok.ru/dk?cmd=AnonymLogin&st.cmd=anonymLogin&tkn=2309&st.posted=set&st.email=почта&st.password=пароль&button_go=%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8");
    System.out.println(response);
}

public static String sendRequest(String url) {
    String inputLine = "";
    String resp = "";
    String buf = "";
    try {
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", user_agent);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
        System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                con.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine+"\n");
        }
        in.close();
        resp = response.toString();
        Map<String, List<String>> map = con.getHeaderFields();
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            buf += entry.getKey() + entry.getValue() + "\n";
        }
        buf += "\n";
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Request error.");
    }
    return buf + resp;
}
}
```

Запрос через Charles:

[image]

Ответ:

[image]

Помогите, пожалуйста.